# getting my form to autofill when editing using

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, edit

very new to mvc. My problem is when I have a record I want to edit my view does not autofill the form. Specifically I am trying to enter a bid on an auction site. I want everything else to stay the same and only update the bid. if my form doesn't autofill then everything would be null.  any help would be appreciated.

```html
this is from the CarAuctionController


        // GET: CarAuction/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int id= 3)
        {
            
            CarList carList = db.CarLists.Find(id);
            
            return View();
        }

        // POST: CarAuction/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(CarList carlist)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add update logic here

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.Entry(carlist).State=EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }

                return View("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }



this is from the view Edit.cshtml

@model ClassicCarAuction.CarList

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>CarList</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ModelYear, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ModelYear, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ModelYear, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Make, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Make, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Make, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Model, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Model, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Model, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CarImage, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CarImage, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CarImage, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DatePosted, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DatePosted, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DatePosted, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AuctionEndDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AuctionEndDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AuctionEndDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReserveBid, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReserveBid, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReserveBid, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PosterUserID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PosterUserID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PosterUserID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ViewingLocation, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ViewingLocation, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ViewingLocation, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HighestBid, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HighestBid, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HighestBid, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HighBidUserId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HighBidUserId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HighBidUserId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Status, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Status, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Status, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing the retrieved carlist model to the view. Therefore the view does not have access to the model and is not able to fill in the form.

```
// GET: CarAuction/Edit/5
public ActionResult Edit(int id= 3)
{

    CarList carList = db.CarLists.Find(id);

    // Change this:
    return View(carList);
}
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you returning "view", but you do not supply the "model" in which the engine can bind them together, thus the default is null.

```
return View("Index");
```

should be

```
return View("Index", carlist);
```